# Creating column with datatypes with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, types, multiple-columns

I have a DataFrame df:

```
A   B
1   dog 
cat XX
```

I have been trying to create a pandas DataFrame df_new that looks like this:

```
A   B    type_of_A   type_of_B
1   dog  int         string
cat XX   string      whateverdtype it may be
```

I tried with:

```
df_new["type_of_A"] = [pd.api.types.infer_dtype(i) for i in range(df_new['A'].values)]
```

But I only got:

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar
>   index

Can anyone give me a hint? is this the right approach?

Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `applymap` with `type`, the `concat` back

```
s=df.applymap(type).add_prefix('type_of_')
df=pd.concat([df,s],1)
Out[543]: 
     A    B      type_of_A      type_of_B
0    1  dog  <class 'int'>  <class 'str'>
1  cat   XX  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
```

Comment: is there a way to apply this procedure to individual columns instead to the whole df? because I believe that "applymap" does not work on series.

Comment: @iraciv94 just do s.apply(type) for series